# CSS not working in IE 11 compatibility mode

Tags: html, css

My app old version is bound to be used in IE 11 compatibility mode to function properly. I am trying to add an overlay with loading animation but my css isn't working. `mainContentGrey` CSS is working but not the `spinner` css.

It works fine without compatibility mode but my apps others functionality stops working.

I would like to know if is there a way or tweak make my css work in IE compatibility mode and what exactly is breaking my css in compatibility mode?

`mainContentGrey`  CSS is working but not the `spinner`, why?

I can see overlay but not the spinner.

```js
function processingSubmit() {

  var check;
  if ((check = document.getElementById('mainContentGrey')) != null) {
    document.getElementById('mainContentGrey').style.display = 'block';
  }
  var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
  var verOffset;
  if ((verOffset = nAgt.indexOf("Firefox")) != -1) {
    var pb = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    pb.style.display = '';
  } else {
    //  showProgress();
  }
}
```

```css
#mainContentGrey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkslategrey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  MozOpacity: 0.5;
  zIndex: 90;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  text-align: center
}

.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner>div {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div><button onclick="processingSubmit()">Click me</button></div>

<div id="mainContentGrey">
  <div id="spinner" class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `is not working proberly` is not a very accurate description. What is not working? What outcome do you get? what outcome is expected? Also note that IE is starting to be decomissioned at 17th August 2021 (start date for MS 365 users) and will be finished to be decomissioned at the 30th November 2021 (Windows 10 Pro users).

Comment: Hello @tacoshy, I get only overlay without spinner.

Comment: @skr get [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) it will solve your issue